# What is the principle of switching views in Compose Desktop?

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, view, compose-desktop

When I want to switch views in Compose Desktop how should I do this? Should I make like a `Column` holding multiple views and switch one invisible and the other one visible (perhaps with an animation) or do I reassign some property holding only one view?

I know there are such libraries as Decompose, but I'd like to understand the basics for my simple app with just two or three different views.

Comment: Without animating the transition, all you need is `if(condition) ComposableA() else ComposableB()`. With animation , refer to the flow chart here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/introduction

Comment: @Tenfour04 there's also the `androidx.navigation` library. Would you say it's android specific or is it safe to use it for desktop apps too?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I believe it's not possible. The package installs, but the namespace does not show up when you type `import androidx.navigation`.

Comment: Yes, navigation is Android specific and tightly coupled to the way Android does things.

Comment: There are a few Multiplatform navigation libraries that are well developed. I really like using Decompose. But there is also Voyager and Decompose-Router.